# HTML page in WEBVIEW is slow and laggy

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on an jQuery Mobile application which uses HTML pages for UI
There are some JS function through which i call some native functions. There are some popups and dialogs with input fields, but when i open some dialog or popup in html the logCat gives me this warning

```
W/webview_proxy(8104): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread
'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of
WebView may not support use on other threads.
```

and while entering values in these input fields page and keyboard  starts blinking. 
that's how i am calling theses native functions

**JS Function**

```
function SettingMethod()
{
activity.setSettings();
}
```

**Android Method**

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void setSettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    final String webServiceURL = settings.getString("URL", "");
    final String InputFolder = settings.getString("INPUTFOLDER", "");
    final String OutPutFolder = settings.getString("OUTPUTFOLDER", "");

  index.loadUrl("javascript:setSettings('" + webServiceURL + "','"
                    + InputFolder + "','" + OutPutFolder + "')");
  }
```

how can i remove this lag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     index.loadUrl("javascript:setSettings('" + webServiceURL + "','"
                    + InputFolder + "','" + OutPutFolder + "')");
                    }
                });
```